# change the browser tab titles based on link clicks using jquery

Tags: jquery

In html code i have a title with name `NAC`

```
 <title>NAC</title>
```

and following links in my webpage

```
 <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li id="home"><a  href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li id="req"><a  href="/reg.html">send request</a></li>
            <li id="agenda"><a  href="/agenda.html">agenda</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
```

what i want is while clicking the `send request` link browser tab title will show `NAC -send request` 
and `agenda` will be

```
NAC -agenda
```

i tried following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#req').click(function(){
      var origTitle = document.title;
document.title = origTitle+"-send request ";
    });
});
```

but it is not working .browser tab still shows NAC only with out appending send request text

Comment: Works for me, are you sure the event handler fires?

Comment: @Sush: After clicking on a link page redirect to the specific location(href)

Comment: It isn't going to work since clicking on the `<a>` will take you to it's `href` location and the title will be set with what is set in the `<title>` for the new page.  So you will never see it change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Check this <kbd>[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bcB6/1/)</kbd>

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#req').click(function(){
      var origTitle = $("title#1").text();
      $("title").text( origTitle + "-send request ");
    });
});
```

#### CSS

```
title{
    display:block;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<title id="1">NAC</title>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li id="home"><a  href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li id="req"><a  href="/req.html">send request</a></li>
        <li id="agenda"><a  href="/agenda.html">agenda</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Here i'm add id in title tag because without this can not identify this title text. i know this is only one but without id in this case i can not find so i add ID attributes.